# How do I put complex order by code into the model?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I need to order database objects by relevance. Relevance is like this: `rating / distance(lat0, lng0, lat, lng)`. I could probably do it this way in a controller:

```
MyModel::orderBy('rating / FUNC(:lat0, :lng0, lat, lng)', [$lat, $lng])
```

But first, there's rather going to be another argument, since latitude appears twice in the formula:

```
MyModel::orderBy('rating / FUNC(:lat0, :lng0, lat, lng)', [$lat, $lat, $lng])
```

Second, it doesn't sound too good to have it in a controller at all. There I'd like to do:

```
MyModel::orderByRelevance($lat, $lng)
```

So, my idea is to extract the sql formula into helper function `sql_distance_to($lat_col_name, $lng_col_name)`. Then, add one more helper: `sql_distance_to_args($lat, $lng)`, which returns `[$lat, $lat, $lng]`. And use these two in the model to make the last statement possible. What do you say? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this by defining a dynamic scope in your model (see [Eloquent query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes)), keeping the logic in your model & re-usable throughout your application:

```
class MyModel extends Model {

    public function scopeRelevance($query, $lat, $lng)
    {
        // Your relevancy calculation.

        // Return query builder instance.
        return $query->where('...');
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
MyModel::relevance($lat, $lng)->get();
```